# RegularExpressionValidator which ignore spaces

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a problem with a RegularExpressionValidator in asp. I want to use it to validate a field in my page. This field is used to enter an alphanumeric value (which can contains any caracters between 0-9, a-z and A-Z). This value can have a maximum of 16 alphanumeric caracters. But, it can contains a boundless number of white spaces, placed anywhere in the string.

If I could, I would use a function such as "replace" in order to remove white spaces and just count the alphanumeric caracters. But, in the case of a RegularExpressionValidator, I just can use a regex ...

Any suggestions :-) ?

Here some value that I want to match :

> - BG R 7K8 15 H8 14
> - 7H96EH L QP0 4634 94
> - 8HL9Q2LRRP18M634

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve the case:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]\s*){1,16}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(      # Start of group
     [A-Za-z0-9]  # Allow a-Z and 0-9
     \s*          # Followed by any number of spaces, including none
)      # End of group
{1,16} # Repeat group 1-16 times
$      # End of string
```